# Selecting most important features for multilinear regression

Tags: regression, statistics, feature-selection, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have a set of 25 features. I would like to choose the best features for my model. Originally, I was looking at the correlation of features with respect to response, and only taking those which are highly correlated and run a regression model. Then, using that model I would predict the outcome based on test data, and compare it to actual (metric **RMSE**) and this would be how I assess it.

I could then add each feature in order of decreasing correlation with response to the feature set and keep calculating above.

Is there any other way I could select features? Could I e.g. run a random forest and use a feature importance report from that to also select the most important features? Then run a regression?

What is the best way to compare each regression model to the next? There are so many metrics: AIC, BIC, ADJ $R^2$ I am confused as to which one is the simplest way to compare... in fact, MSE is not even given in the sm.OLS function (stats models in python) summary:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful choosing features based on correlation! Yes it is true that features that are correlated with the response variable may be good predictors, however if the features are correlated with *each other* then you are introducing [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) into your model, which is bad.

If you want to avoid this you should choose features which are correlated with your response variable but not with each other. For example...

y = a + b + c

Assume:
y is correlated with all three (a, b, c)

a is correlated with b

c is not correlated with a and b

You should only use one of either a or b and c to predict y.

With regard to choosing which model is best, you should use a combination of metrics. As you increase the number of features your R^2 will tend to increase regardless of model performance. AIC and BIC can be used only to compare similar models and the "best" model according to AIC/BIC will be the one with the lowest score *relative to the other models*.

In my opinion RMSE is the best indicator of a good model, but you should also evaluate R^2, AIC, and BIC.

If you are unsure of which features to use I suggest you try [stepwise regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression) to evaluate many models quickly and (maybe) find the best one.

Comment: How would I then interpret and compare the importance of features as here? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508612/how-to-interpret-coefficients-relative-to-one-another-regression-continuous-an

Answer (score 1):

Consider playing around with LASSO or Ridge-regressions, as these punish features with low predictive power. These are simple and strong methods for linear purposes.

Your idea of using the feature importance from Random Forest could also be a suitable solution in cases of non-linearity.

Comment: If I use ridge regression I will standardize my predictive inputs right?.

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, standardization is not necessary for LASSO.